# Loading Images from resource or different folders

Tags: java, imageicon, javax.imageio, getresource

I create a custom class that extends `ImageIcon`, so that passing the file url and a given color, it loads the image repainting it.
This class is packed in a .jar file I use for developing different user interfaces (let's call it `UI.jar`).

This class should be conceived for loading both the images located in a folder packed inside `UI.jar`, other images packed in another .jar file, other images with other urls, possibly located in folders not packed in a .jar. So I developed this code:

```
BufferedImage bi = null;
try{
    //CASE 1: the image related to this url is packed in a .jar file
    bi = ImageIO.read(resourceClass.getResource(url));
}catch(Exception e){
    try{
        //CASE 2: the image related to this url is somewhere else
        bi = ImageIO.read(new File(url));
    }catch(Exception ee){
        //CASE 3: none of the above
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This method works, but the problem is that I have always to pass `resourceClass` as an arguments of my custom class which extends ImageIcon and this is a bit tricky and uncomfortable.

Are there other ways to achieve my objective?

Comment: Minor performance/code issue: There's no need for the outer `try/catch`. Instead, you can just test if `Class.getResource(url)` returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I see three alternatives here

1. getClass().getResource(String)
2. ImplementationClassName.class.getResource(String)
3. Reflection.getCallerClass().getResource(String)

Any of those should do the job.

After you did not like the first three you can try this, but this is even more ugly.

```
StackTraceElement[] se = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
//se[0] = Thread.getStackTrace()
//se[1] = your method
//se[2] = your callers method
Class x = Class.forName(se[2].getClassName());
x.getResource(url);
```

Comment: Also `getClass().getClassLoader()`

Comment: The prolem is that `getClass()` method always return the class where it is called and, in my case, the class packed in `UI.jar`. So, if the url that I pass as argument refers to a file located in another directory or packed in another jar (where `UI.jar` is a dependency of this jar), the method doesn't work.

Comment: in this case Reflection.getCallerClass is yours.

Comment: @tejoe it seems that this methods belongs to the `sun.reflect` package and unfortunately I'm not able to get it.

Comment: Why not just use the current `Thread`'s `ClassLoader`? Seems a bit more straightforward and less hacky.